# How do you create a function similar to eval(), but stops when it goes into the negatives?

Tags: python

I am creating this project and I am currently using `eval()` to evaluate some strings, but I need to stop it whenever it goes into the negatives. Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Say I did 4 * (3 - 9). At one point in the equation, it went into negatives. I want to write a function that stops evaluating the equation as soon as it goes into negatives.

Comment: So what would be the output for `4 * (3 - 9)`? Also, do not use `eval` this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your limited description is that you want to evaluate an expression, and stop when it becomes negative. Here is proof-of-concept :

```py
import ast


class NegativeValue(Exception):
    pass


def recursively_eval_tree(t: ast.AST):
    if isinstance(t, ast.BinOp):
        left = recursively_eval_tree(t.left)
        right = recursively_eval_tree(t.right)
        result = {
            ast.Add: left + right,
            ast.Sub: left - right,
            ast.Mult: left * right,
        }[type(t.op)]
        if result < 0:
            raise NegativeValue
        else:
            return result
    elif isinstance(t, ast.Constant):
        result = t.value
        if result < 0:
            raise NegativeValue
        else:
            return result
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(type(t))


def eval_but_not_negative(expression_str):
    expression_tree = ast.parse(expression_str, mode='eval')
    if not isinstance(expression_tree, ast.Expression):
        raise ValueError("not an expression")
    try:
        return recursively_eval_tree(expression_tree.body)
    except NegativeValue:
        return "negative value"


print(eval_but_not_negative("4 * (3 + 9)"))  # 48
print(eval_but_not_negative("4 * (3 - 9)"))  # "negative value"
```

It uses the [`ast` moduke](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse the expression string into a Python tree, then recursively evaluate the nodes of the tree to compute intermediary results. At each step, it checks if the current value is negative, in which case it will raise an exception, to be caught by the wrapper, which will return another value then the mathematical result.